# Angular Leaflet add numbers to custom iconUrl markers

Tags: css, angular, leaflet, icons, markers

I want to add numbered markers in Leaflet map ,

though Im using custom images as markers iconUrls ,

the numbers doesn't feet with the custom icons

this is my code.

```
              this.marker1 = marker([52.316336, 10.637616],{
                icon: new L.Icon({
                   // className:'my-custom-icon',
                  html: (i+1).toString(),
                   iconSize: [ 25, 41 ],
                   iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
                   iconUrl: iconUrl
                })
              });
```

the iconUrl value is a static path for images stored in assets folder.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A `L.Icon` doesn't take a `html` option, as per [the docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon), so that code cannot produce any numbers, so it's impossible that you have misaligned numbers. Is that really your actual code?

Comment: yes , I tried html with divIcon , for L.Icon I checked on the Internet and did not find any clue on how to achived with custom icons , it worked only with divIcon and display the markers in circular marker not with the default leaflet markers

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787971/creating-map-in-leaflet-with-numbered-pins-or-markers , then (comments there would apply here as well). Consider rephrasing your question.